# How to call an API by ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run an `ajax` call to an external URL using "CORS Anywhere".It worked fine but now resulting this error : `Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`
I just can't understand why this would happen

```
var CORS = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
$.ajax({
url: CORS + 'https://egtapp.com/bc/hotel/123456/inf/json/api/',
dataType: "json",
type: "GET",
success: function (jsonObject, status) {
    console.log(jsonObject)
},

});
```

Comment: Is this a valid URL?

Answer (score 1):

Attach header `x-requested-with`:

```
var CORS = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
$.ajax({
url: CORS + 'https://egtapp.com/bc/hotel/123456/inf/json/api/',
headers:{"x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},
dataType: "json",
type: "GET",
success: function (jsonObject, status) {
    console.log(jsonObject)
},
});
```

Comment: Url  will be shown in network tab two times and  there is no result in both of them

Comment: @Mona this url showing 404 error :- http://egtapp.com/bc/hotel/123456/inf/json/api/

Comment: @Mona https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ cannot access https://basiscore.com/en/bc/hotel/id/1206759/inf/json because of headers sent by `cors-anywhere` website are not valid for API(`basiscore.com`). Our bad luck.

Comment: So there is not any solution for it!?:(

Comment: You cannot access API from AJAX or Cross origin requests. I think there is no way if website is token protected

Comment: Thank you @Ritesh Khandekar for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check url first. you r adding ***CORS + 'https://egtapp.com/bc/hotel/123456/inf/json/api/' *** which means you want get something 
from following link:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://egtapp.com/bc/hotel/123456/inf/json/api/
I don't think this a valid url..
After ensuring url, you can write:

```
$.ajax({
url:"your url from where u want to get data"
method: "GET",
success: function (jsonObject, status) {
    console.log(jsonObject);
},
error: function (err){
console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This is my valid url :

Comment: By adding https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ ther  would be this error

Comment: Is this the url from where u fetch tha data?
[link]https://basiscore.com/en/bc/hotel/id/1206759/inf/json

Answer (score 0):

Mona, I think that is not from cors anywhere, that message comes from your target URL.
So you should attach that header.